# Solve the PDE $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+\sin t$ by separation of variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Use separation of variables to solve the PDE $$u_{tt}=u_{xx}+\sin t$$ for $$t \ge0, \ \ \ \  \ -\infty <x < +\infty$$ such that $$u(x, 0)=0 $$ and $$u_x(0,t)=0$$.

I substituted in $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ and got $$X(x)T''(t)=X''(x)T(t)+\sin t$$Then do I divide by $X(x)T(t)$? And what do I do after that and so on?

Comment: try instead of using the method of separation of variable, Fourier transform with respect to $x$ both sides

Comment: Just as a note - by inspection $-\sin (t)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when your PDE has a non-homogeneous part such as $\sin(t)$, you want to solve for the steady state solution fist, and then do a change of variables to turn it into a problem that's solvable by separation of variables. In other words, if we can get rid of the $\sin(t)$ term, then the PDE simplifies into something that you probably already know how to solve.

By inspection, let $v(x,t) = u(x,t) + \sin(t)$. Then,
\begin{align}
  v_{tt} &= u_{tt} - \sin(t)\\
  v_{xx} &= u_{xx}\\
\end{align} 
Which transforms the PDE into
\begin{align}
  (v_{tt} + \sin(t)) &= v_{xx} + \sin(t)\\
  \Rightarrow v_{tt} &= v_{xx}
\end{align}
For the boundary conditions, 
\begin{align}
  v(x,0) &= u(x,0) + \sin(0) = u(x,0) = 0\\
  v_x(0,t) &= u_x(0,t) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(t) = 0 + 0 = 0
\end{align}
In summary, we have that
\begin{align}
  v_{tt} &= v_{xx}\\
  v(x,0) &= 0 \\
  v_x(0,t) &= 0
\end{align}
Which you can solve by separation of variables.

Comment: Shouldn't the second boundary condition be $v_x(0,t)=$...?

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct. In fact, that boundary condition simplifies the problem tremendously. I've fixed my answer :)